# Maximum eigenvalue of symmetric matrix

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let's consider S a square, symmetric matrix, why the maximum eigenvalue is given by:
$$ \lambda_{max}(S) = \max_{x: ||x||_2=1} x^T S x$$

By the EVD of symmetric matrices, I will agree if we restricted $x$ to be an eigenvector because:

$$ u_i^T S u_i = \lambda_i ||u_i||^2 $$

but I seem to miss a step to get the result without the restriction for $x$ to be an eigenvector.

Comment: Hint: the eigenvectors of symmetric matrices can be chosen to be orthonormal and complete. So for any $x$ write $x=\sum_i (x,v_i)v_i$ and rewrite the maximization in terms of it.

Comment: This is spectral theorem. The biggest eigenvalue of a symmetric compact operator (here an operator of finite rank, hence compact) is it's norm. $\max x^TSx$ is just another description of that norm that works when a matrix (or operator in general) is symmetric.